# ASP.NET Add column to Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that is displaying data from a database using LINQ to SQL.

```
AssetDataContext db = new AssetDataContext();
equipmentGrid.DataSource = db.equipments.OrderBy(n => n.EQCN);
```

I need to add a column at the end of the girdview that will have links to edit/delete/view the row. I need the link to be "http://localhost/edit.aspx?ID=" + idOfRowItem.

Comment: you need this one: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/create_template_columns.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a TemplateField to your GridView like so:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="http://localhost/edit.aspx?ID=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %>">Edit</a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Within the item template you can place any links you like and bind any data you wish to them from your DataSource. In the example above I have just pulled the value from a column named id.

As things stand this would work fine, however the column above would be aligned left most in the GridView with all the auto generated columns to its right.

To fix this you can add a handler for the RowCreated event and move the column to the right of the auto generated columns like so:

```
gridView1.RowCreated += new GridViewRowEventHandler(gridView1_RowCreated);

...

void gridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = e.Row;
    TableCell actionsCell = row.Cells[0];
    row.Cells.Remove(actionsCell);
    row.Cells.Add(actionsCell);
}
```

Hope this helps.