# Add column(s) in front of the GridView column in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my project, it is a table which shows some details of someone and a button to do somethings.

The table looks like:

```
-----------------------------
name | detail | other | Btn |
name | detail | other | Btn |
name | detail | other | Btn |
name | detail | other | Btn |
name | detail | other | Btn |
name | detail | other | Btn |
```

However, i cannot add those column in front of the Btn column which the Btn column is defined with asp GridView control and others columns are defined with dataTable in C#.

Therefore, How do i add those column in C#?

Code:
GridView:

```
                  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" /> // if i remove these => errors
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="detail" HeaderText="detail" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="other" HeaderText="other" />

                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Image/btn.png" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                       </Columns>
                   </asp:GridView>
```

Code: dataTable

```
        var DT = new DataTable();
        DT .Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));// if i remove these => errors
        DT .Columns.Add("Detail", typeof(string));
        DT .Columns.Add("other", typeof(string));

      .....foreach loop
                 DataRow dr = DT .NewRow();
                 dr["Name"] = item["Name"];
                 dr["Detail"] = item["Detail"];
                 dr["other"] = item["other"];
                 waitDT.Rows.Add(dr);
      .....end of foreach loop

        GridView1.DataSource = DT;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

So, the result i getting is:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
name | detail | other | Btn | name | detail | other |
name | detail | other | Btn | name | detail | other |
name | detail | other | Btn | name | detail | other |
name | detail | other | Btn | name | detail | other |
name | detail | other | Btn | name | detail | other |
name | detail | other | Btn | name | detail | other |
```

**Main Question:**

I want to define the btn column in asp control and others in C#.

it should look like:

```
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Image/btn.png" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                       </Columns>
                   </asp:GridView>
```

then the C#:

```
    var DT = new DataTable();
    DT .Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));//it should place in front of the btn column
    DT .Columns.Add("Detail", typeof(string));
    DT .Columns.Add("other", typeof(string));

  .....foreach loop
             DataRow dr = DT .NewRow();
             dr["Name"] = item["Name"];
             dr["Detail"] = item["Detail"];
             dr["other"] = item["other"];
             waitDT.Rows.Add(dr);
  .....end of foreach loop

    GridView1.DataSource = DT;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

finally the result:

```
-----------------------------
name | detail | other | Btn |
name | detail | other | Btn |
name | detail | other | Btn |
name | detail | other | Btn |
name | detail | other | Btn |
name | detail | other | Btn |
```

Comment: Isn't there an AutoGenerate property on the data grid view.

Comment: what error ocurred? when you remove?

Comment: @user6002727 ya, when i remove the column definition, the error will be occurred.

Comment: @kingyau what is that error? elaborate please?

Comment: @user6002727 the error is "Sorry, something went wrong
An unexpected error has occurred."

Comment: what is the value inside the DT?

Comment: @user6002727 please check my update of the creation of dataTable.

Answer (score 1):

i solve it!

it is petty simple by following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521136/asp-net-add-column-to-gridview?rq=1).

Code in asp control:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Image/btn.png" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

code in C#

```
gridView1.RowCreated += new GridViewRowEventHandler(gridView1_RowCreated);

...

void gridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = e.Row;
    TableCell actionsCell = row.Cells[0];
    row.Cells.Remove(actionsCell);
    row.Cells.Add(actionsCell);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem.

my original code:

```
 var DT = new DataTable();
    DT .Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));//it should place in front of the btn column
    DT .Columns.Add("Detail", typeof(string));
    DT .Columns.Add("other", typeof(string));

  .....foreach loop
             DataRow dr = DT .NewRow();
             dr["Name"] = item["Name"];
             dr["Detail"] = item["Detail"];
             dr["other"] = item["other"];
             waitDT.Rows.Add(dr);
  .....end of foreach loop

GridView1.DataSource = DT;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

The problem is that i am using var to declare the dataTable. I don't know what type of it is declared, however, when i using `DataTable` to declare it, all work well!

```
DataTable DT = new DataTable();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Setting AutoGenerateProperty to false on the gridview.

Comment: not work. i think the question is the gridview has 4 columns, but the dataTabe has 3 only.

Comment: if i remove those three column which only keep the btn column, the btn column will be the first column that i want to set it to the last one.

Answer (score -1):

Code in aspx

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" /> 
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Detail" HeaderText="Detail" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="other" HeaderText="other" />

                                <asp:TemplateField >
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:Button ID="buttonReject" Text="Reject" runat="server"   />
                                    </ItemTemplate>

                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />

                                </asp:TemplateField>
                           </Columns>
                       </asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind

```
 foreach (....)
    {
        DataRow dr = DT.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = item["Name"];
        dr["Detail"] = item["Detail"];
        dr["other"] = item["other"];
        DT.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
     GridView1.DataSource = DT;
     GridView1.DataBind();
```